# Check if site is inside iframe

Tags: php, iframe

Anyone know if it's possible to check if a site is inside an iframe with PHP.

I know it's possible with javascript, but i couldn't find any example with PHP?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

PHP is never in an iframe. PHP is executed on the server side and generates output such as HTML, Javascript, or text. The output generated by PHP may produce or reside within an iframe, but never PHP itself.

---

**ADDITIONAL DETAIL**

With regard to the additional detail you added in comments (that you want to distinguish between requests directly to your site and requests via a Facebook application) there are a few techniques you can use:

1. **$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']:**

You can check the referrer to determine if a request came from a Facebook URL, from another page on your own site, from a third-party site, or if it was direct traffic. This method is not foolproof, but may provide more information than your application currently receives.

2. **Separate URLs**

You can create separate URLs for the application running on your site and the Facebook version. Using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, you can easily detect whether your application was accessed via 'yoursite.com/fbapp' or 'yoursite.com/localapp'. Both URLs can reference the same scripts via Apache's mod_rewrite or the aliasing solution of your choice.

3. **URL Parameters**

This method is possibly the easiest to implement. If you can provide URL parameters when you provide an application URL to Facebook, just add a parameter. For example:

```
?access_method=facebook
```

In PHP, you can easily check for the existence and value of the `access_method` parameter, and take action as necessary.

Answer (score 41):

For anyone who lands on this old thread: There is a very easy way to check in PHP wether or not your page is loaded through an iframe.

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST'] == 'iframe' ) {}
```

Comment: Good solution! worked perfectly with a Wordpress plugin where I did not want scripts to be enqueued in iFrames. Thank you.

Comment: I Can't find documentation that iframe is a valid value for this field, nor could I find too much else on the sec-fetch-dest header. Do you have a link or resource as to how this work? Is it supported in every browser? Works in chrome and does exactly what I need it to do but just want to clarification as to it's browser support.

Comment: Geilt, I could also not found any info about that. So I simply starting comparing all $_SERVER with and without iFrame, through a proxy, or direct, using yes/no Adguard (and alike). A lot of $_SERVER variables where there with other values. The ONLY one that always showed us in an iFrame (not matter the connection) is $_SERVER['HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST'].

Comment: This header is not supported on IE, Firefox and Safari - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-Dest#browser_compatibility

Comment: @Ismail supported only on firefox 90 above and chrome.. safari doesn't. Only using window.location.. ah..

Comment: Luckily most browsers have added this. Only Opera Android does not support this header. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-Dest#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 8):

No, PHP is server side. It has no way of knowing if it is in a iframe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's because people can use my app via. facebook apps or directly in the browser. So if the user is on my app on facebook, the link should be something different, than if the user is on my site directly in the browser and not through facebook. Any idea of how i can do that?

Comment: @Simon The way to go here is to check with javascript if the page is loaded in an iframe or not. Read more about that here: http://www.24hourapps.com/2009/01/check-if-page-is-loaded-in-iframe-using.html

Comment: @Ancide it need to be with some kind of PHP

Comment: @Simon Sorry, but it's not possible to get a fast, straightforward and accurate solution in PHP. Best practice is to use javascript to handle this.

Comment: @Ancide yearh, that's a bit annoying

Comment: did you ever find a viable solution for this? I am having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
if(!$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'YourFrameURL') {
    // Site is NOT loaded from iframe
    die('Please load this page from YourFrameURL');
}
else {
    // Site IS loaded from iframe: display content
?>
```

Please note that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is totally not reliable: it can be modified. Also note that this method is 'https-sensitive'. If the frame is loaded from `https://x` while `YourFrameURL` is set to `http://x`, it will not work. Fix this by using:

```
if(!$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://YourFrameURL' or !$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'https://YourFrameURL') {
```

Comment: It's actually: `if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != 'http://YourFrameURL') { }` checkign if referer is set at all AND different than your url

Answer (score 4):

You can check for `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. This cannot really be trusted because browsers not always provide this information. Also `HTTP_REFERER` not always means an iframe but for particular cases this is good.

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] output the correct url on facebook, but on my site directly through the browser, I get this error: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not set when you go to the site directly. You can test it using this: `if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) { ... }`.

Comment: Looks like that solution works. I'll test it in IE and return back! :-)

Comment: @Simon Also, I do recommend to check if `HTTP_REFERER` is a particular URL in facebook, because if some other site has a direct link to your site and somebody came to your site throw this link then `HTTP_REFERER` will be equal to the URL the user came from.

Comment: Yes, that's right. If i come from facebook via. a link, the url will be apps.facebook.com/application, because the script think i'm a using the application through facebook :s

Comment: @Simon Maybe I don't understand something, but this should not be a problem. Where somebody can find a link to your site through _apps.facebook.com/application_ ?

Comment: @Zenklys fully trusted solutions is not always needed. It depends particular applications needs :)

Comment: @Karolis yes, in certain applications, it is ok. But in this case, the HTTP_REFERER is a browser header. That means you are breaking compatibility for of portion of users. Which is IMHO a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but you can use `Sec-Fetch-Dest` header retrieved from [`getallheaders()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php), i.e.:

```
$all_headers = getallheaders();
if(@$all_headers['Sec-Fetch-Dest'] == "iframe"){
    # iframe request
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I find a workaround that can implement with php + javascript.
On first url on your iframe set parameter `iframe_view=true` and next use this js to put on all links this url parameter again

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $("a").attr('href', function(index, item) {
     return item + (item.indexOf('?') != -1 ? "&iframe_view=true" : "?iframe_view=true");
   });
});
</script>
```

And then read it with php like:

```
if (isset($_GET['iframe_view'])) {
//iframe view
}
```