# prevent php files htacces

Tags: php, .htaccess, iframe, security

How I prevent acces for all php files inside a folder with htacces but when I want acces through iframe works fine?

I don't want that the users accessing through url because it would be a security bug..

Any answer?

Comment: Please explain the difference between "accessing through URL" and "access through iframe". Don't you set the source of the iframe to the same URL? If directly accessing your script opposes a security threat, then make your script secure.

Comment: Partial duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662542/check-if-site-is-inside-iframe - both PHP and Mod-Rewrite cannot determine if something is an iframe. They handle the request and send it back regardless. Also, it will be just as insecure through an iframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing a page via an iframe is the same as accessing it via a url.  If you make the page inaccessible in that way then the iframe will not be able to load it either.

Comment: Thanks @D-Rock, but i don't want that the users accessing via url but I want that in a iframe it works..

Answer (score 1):

This just is not possible. You cannot have what you want. You can think of an iframe as a browser within a browser. An iframe makes an independent fresh GET request to your server for the content's URL, with no indication that it is being used in an iframe.

However, once the page has been delivered to the client, you can have the page run some javascript to check if it is an iframe and delete it's own content if it isn't.

```
if (top === self) {
  // not in an iframe. delete all the content
  document.body.innerHTML = 'Not allowed';
}
```

You could invert this to deliver invisible content, but have the javascript make the content visible if `top != self`

Now, of course, this only affects the visibility of the content to the user. It is still being delivered and a power-user can still interact with it. This is only a bit of visual  trickery - there is zero security.