# issues with Iframe and php include

Tags: php, html, iframe, header, include

I'm new to PHP and i use the include function to include a header file that has my db connections and my menu. On a body page I'm using a iframe to include a aside that needs to go on many different pages. The issue arises when i hit click on one of the hyperlinks of the aside that is in the IFRAME it will take me to the proper page BUT will RE-include the header in that portion of the code. I was wondering if there is any alternatives OR ways to insure the header doesn't reload in my iframe. Here is a copy of my code.

Main PAGE

```
<?php 
include_once("include/header.php");

?>
<div id="content">
 <div id="left" class="sidebar">
<iframe src="aside.php" height="550" frameborder="0" width="210" scrolling="no"      allowtransparency="true" rel="nofollow"></iframe>
 </div>
```

Aside page

```
<div class="imgholder">
      <p class="employeename">Pablo Israel Penaloza</p>
      <img src="img/Pablo-Peñaloza.jpg" width="202" height="150" class="imgemployee">
      <div class="sidebarmenu">
    <ul id="sidebarmenu1">
          <li><a href="personalinfo.php">Informacion Personal</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact de Emergencia</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dependientes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Imigracion</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Deberes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Salario</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Supervisor</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Calificaciones</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Membresias</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    <!--End sidebarmenu1--> 
  </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: stop using iframes, they are well passed there use by date.

Comment: Unless of course there is a need to use them... like you're showing someone else's content. (Like video streaming.)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use javascript for the detection, or make separate URLs for pages that will be included in the iframe. This should help you:
[Check if site is inside iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662542/check-if-site-is-inside-iframe)

**To not use an iframe would be best.**
It's much easier if you just use `include()`. You can make the content that would reside in the `iframe` inside of a scrolling `DIV` instead. Modern sites do this and update the `<div>` with [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp).

**To make it scroll**

```
<div style='width:210px;height:550px;overflow:auto'>
   <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/aside.php'); ?>
</div>
```

**Static**

```
<div style='width:210px;height:550px;'>
   <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/aside.php'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: @user2328338 Did it answer the question?

Comment: Thanks absoluteZERO, bloody genius, better than using iframes too.