# How can I check if site is inside iframe in symfony?

Tags: symfony-1.4

Is it possible to check if a site is inside an iframe with symfony?
I do not want do it via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Symfony request for the Sec-Fetch-Site header.  That will indicate that it's in an iframe.

Answer (score -1):

That is not possible because Symfony (PHP) runs on the server and your page is being rendered on the client.

You could tell Symfony that a page is rendered inside an iframe by adding a querystring with the page request, like `http://my-symfony-site/products/index?iframe=1`, and do a check on the server to see if the `iframe` parameter was provided.

Comment: So I need to place "iframe=1" everywhere I meet the hyperlink? It is not appropriate.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662542/check-if-site-is-inside-iframe) for more details.