# How to recognize if I'm using Facebook Canvas or Website version of Facebook App

Tags: php, facebook, canvas

I'm using a Facebook application to create a kind of "social sharing" platform.
The website version uses Facebook API, Twitter OAuth and Instagram, and the canvas version only uses Facebook API.

I know that, when using the Canvas, Facebook sends a `signed_request` parameter, which actually recognizes that I'm using the Canvas version and not the website version. So, this is my login code:

login.php

```
$is_canvas=$SController->checkIsCanvas();

if(isset($_REQUEST['request_ids'])) {
    $_SESSION['auth_request']=strip_tags($_GET['request_ids']);
}
```

socialclass.php

```
function checkIsCanvas() {
        $helper = new FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();
        try {
            $session = $helper->getSession();
        } catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
            return $ex->getMessage();
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return $ex->getMessage(); 
        }
        if ($session) {
            $_SESSION['is_canvas']='true';
            $accessToken=$session->getAccessToken();
            $_SESSION['auth_tk_facebook']=$accessToken->__toString();
            $request = new FacebookRequest(
                $session,
                'GET',
                '/me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,birthday,email,age_range,location,gender'
            );
            $response = $request->execute();
            $userProfile = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
            if(isset($userProfile)) {
                $login=$this->checkFacebookLogin($userProfile);
                if($login===false) {
                    return $userProfile;
                } else {
                    header("Location:".getBASEURL());
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I logout from canvas and then re-login, Facebook hasn't sent any `signed_request` parameter, so I can't recognize if I'm actually using the Canvas version or the website's one. To temporally solve this, I just reload the page, so Facebook can save another `signed_request`, but it's quite annoying.

This problem comes up also when i go from the Canvas version to the website version without logging-out. Obviously, the `is_canvas` session variable doesn't unset, so the `website` version appears equal to the `Canvas` version.

How can I always check if I'm in the canvas, or in the website without reloading after logging-out? The problem should be, I hope, easy to solve, but I've not figured out how to do that yet.

If you have any questions about more pieces of code or if I wasn't as clear as I'm expecting ( sorry for my English, too ) don't worry about asking :)

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar/related Question is solved here : [Check if site is inside iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662542/check-if-site-is-inside-iframe)

Because canvas is always called in iframe. Please check if it helps.

Comment: I'm going to take a look, I've searched a lot on this forum and anything was saying to check `signed_request`. Let's see if this can help, thank you :)