# If my app is being loaded by iframe - can I detect it?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, iframe

I didn't find the information about this topic in google. Can I detect if my (Rails) application is being loaded from iframe? If yes, can I obtain the url of the iframe? I'd like to do it by both javascript and on the server if it's not possible, if not - whatever way is easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

through javascript its very easy.

```
function isInIframe () {
    try {
        return window.self !== window.top;
    } catch (e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

server side , check http referer header.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] but this is not foolproof.
```

[more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662542/check-if-site-is-inside-iframe)

Comment: is it possible to do that on the server, but without ajax?

Comment: how do I get the url of the iframe when using javascript?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp if you do window.top.location.hostname it will give  iframe url