# Check if PHP script is used as <img> source

Tags: php, http-headers

Is it possible to determine if output of PHP script will be used as image or a full site?

I need something like this:

```
<?php
    if(clientRequestedImage()) {
        header("Content-Type: image/png");
        readfile("image.png");
    } else {
        readfile("image-wrapped.html");
    }
?>
```

So when I later use `<img src="script.php">`, an image will be shown and when I open the script using address bar or a link, a HTML document will appear.

How should I implement function `clientRequestedImage`?

Similar question: [Check if site is inside iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662542/check-if-site-is-inside-iframe)

Comment: No, the HTTP referer (even if it was reliable) doesn't give you element-level identification like that. All you'll ever get is the overall page URL. You can TELL the script it should directly spit out an image, e.g. `http://example.com/script.php?isimg`, then `if (isset($_GET['isimg'])) { .... going into an img src ... } else { not an image  src }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: This is just a hunch and I'm not sure if this works in all browsers (should in latest Chrome and Firefox, at least that's what I tested).

You can parse the client's `Accept` HTTP header. The [`Accept` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) is used by the client to specify the media type the browser should send it's response to. Examples for this header are:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
```

Both Chrome and Firefox *seem* to always send an `Accept: text/html,...` header when requesting a regular site, and some variation of `Accept: image/...` when loading an image embedded by an `<img>` tag.

You can access this header in PHP via the `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']` variable. So you *might* be able to do something like this:

```
$acceptedTypes = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']);
if (strstr($acceptedTypes[0], 'text/html') === 0) {
    // Output as HTML page
} else if (strstr($acceptedTypes[0], 'image/') === 0) {
    // Output as image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably to be reusable you'll also need to know the image name or something to reference, so maybe an image tag like:

```
<img src="script.php?image=logo">
```

Then (this is not secure you need to whitelist or otherwise sanitize the get data):

```
if(isset($_GET['image'])) {
    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    readfile($_GET['image'] . "image.png");
} else {
    readfile("image-wrapped.html");
}
```

If not, then something as simple as:

```
<img src="script.php?image">
```

Or:

```
<img src="script.php?html">
```

Then check for `isset($_GET['image'])` etc...

Comment: You didn't answer any of my two questions. If I wanted two different URLs, I would use `<img src="image.png">` and `<a href="site.html">` directly...

Comment: So the answer is NO, you can't.

Comment: I am going to say Maybe. Using URL Rewrite, you might be able to do this. The rewrite condition could look at the extension and call different content based on that.

Answer (score 0):

> You didn't answer any of my two questions. If I wanted two different
>   URLs, I would use `<img src="image.png">` and `<a href="site.html">`
>   directly..

This comment made me think of URL Rewrites. As it is even mentioned in the article that you link to, HTTP Referrer is only 1 option of 3. Like @AbraCadaver mentioned, Option 3 is best, using URL Parameters.

If you insist on doing it in one script, you have to leverage URL Rewrite. This allows you to mask URL Parameters. This way you have some condition to allow PHP to know what to present.

Take your example, when the browser renders the page, it creates an HTTP Request to download the Image file specified by the markup `<IMG>` by it's attribute `SRC`. The browser creates a GET Request for the URL, i.e. `www.example.com/image.png`, and may or may not amend a referrer to the headers. The `<A>` tag renders a link based on the `href` attribute and when the user clicks on this link in their browser, the browser creates a GET request for the URL (sound familiar?), i.e. `www.example.com/site.html`.

Using URL Rewrite, we can examine these two URLs and direct the traffic to the same PHP Script, adjusting the URL Parameters in the background. The request for `/image.png` can become `script.php?image=image.png` and the request for `/site.html` can become `script.php?site=site.html`.