# How to restrict direct access to php file wrapped in Joomla iframe wrapper

Tags: php, angularjs, iframe, joomla, joomla3.5

I am using Joomla Iframe Wrapper to access a php file (books.php).
The link I have create is only accessible to registered users.

However, when soneone type www.mysaplesite.com/books.php they are able to see the content of that php file even though they are not registered.

In what possible way can i restrict DIRECT access to that file/page WITHOUT Joomla.

Note: the books.php is an angularjs app.

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered of a server side redirection? (`.htaccess` if you are using Apache)

Comment: You should read this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662542/check-if-site-is-inside-iframe

Comment: @CPHPython I will love to do that if i could help. How do I do that?

Comment: You can start by knowing if your server is running Apache, nginx or something else and then by reading how to [redirect users](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx) that access that specific page.

Comment: @CPHPython can you give some sample code?

Comment: I can do better than that, use an [.htaccess generator](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/) to provide you the code according to your parameters.

Comment: But anyway, [if you have no idea what are `.htaccess` files you should read about them before modifying them](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html).